# Git pre-commit hook: Prevent commits that change particular files

Tags: git, githooks

I have a few .json files under my project that contain several keys. These keys must not be under version control. I replaced those actual keys with fake ones in my project in order to prevent build fails on continuous integration.

However, developers need to copy/paste these files on their laptop before they are able to test the app.

Now, the problem is a developer might forget and mistakenly commit them into git. I want to run a `pre-commit` script that checks modified files and fails the commit if one of them is being added.

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prevent it on the developer side with a `pre-commit` hook. Note that `git commit --no-verify` will bypass this safety mechanism.

The code below blocks any changes at all to files `dir/key1.json` and `key2.json`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# full paths from the repo root separated by newlines
MUST_NOT_CHANGE='dir/key1.json
key2.json'

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  against=HEAD
else
  # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
  against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

exec 1>&2

if git diff --cached --name-only $against |
   grep --quiet --line-regexp --fixed-strings "$MUST_NOT_CHANGE"
then
  echo Commit would modify one or more files that must not change.
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

The `pre-receive` hook below *that must be installed on your central repository* rejects any push that would modify the protected files.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# full paths from the repo root separated by newlines
MUST_NOT_CHANGE='dir/key1.json
key2.json'

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read old_value new_value ref_name
do
  if [ "$old_value" = $z40 ]; then
    # New branch: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
  else
    against=$old_value
  fi

  if git diff --name-only $against..$new_value |
     grep --quiet --line-regexp --fixed-strings "$MUST_NOT_CHANGE"
  then
    echo "$ref_name" may commit key, rejected ... >&2
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

In action:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 40 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 820 bytes | 410.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: refs/heads/master may commit key, rejected ...
To '<URL>'
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '<URL>'
```

Comment: Wow, awesome Greg. Thank you for giving me all the details. Just one question, What are `against` in the first block and the `z40` in the second block? Should be hardcoded or retrieved somehow?

Comment: Use of `against` handles the case when a branch doesn’t exist yet, but `git diff` needs *something* to diff against. The githooks documentation for `pre-receive` explains the dummy SHA1 of forty zeros means that the ref does not yet exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in pre-commit hook:

```
FILES_PATTERN='<regexp_to_match_file_names>'
if git diff --cached --name-only | grep -qE $FILES_PATTERN; then
    exit 1;
else
    exit 0;
fi
```

The idea is based on these references:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48535/can-grep-return-true-false-or-are-there-alternative-methods
- https://codeinthehole.com/tips/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/

Beware that I did not test this.

Comment: ah, awesome. I'll test it. Thank you for directing me.

Comment: please also note, that developers can still bypass this using no-verify. If you want to be absolutely sure that they can't commit them, then you will need a server-side pre-receive hook.

Comment: I think you can also one-line the `git diff` check with `! git diff --cached --name-only | grep -qE $FILES_PATTERN` by negating the whole expression.